# signalr/hubs getting 404 error on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 when using SignalR

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, signalr, signalr-hub

My development machine is Visual Studio 2013 and the project is a ASP.NET using .NET 4 and  SignalR 1.2.1.

The project works using IIS Express and Local IIS but doesn't work on Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1.

Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 already has [KB980368](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980368) already installed so I don't have to worry about extensionless urls.

The page comes up but the button never gets enabled because signalr/hubs is getting a 404 error.

[I found this link](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/troubleshooting-and-debugging/troubleshooting) but tried everything under 404 and it still doesn't work.
I've also tried everything [on this blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/timlee/archive/2013/03/21/hosting-a-signalr-application-on-windows-2008r2-and-iis-7-5.aspx#10522142) and [this KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2023146) without any success.

I've also compared my local Windows 7 IIS settings to the server and everything seems correct, so I'm really out of ideas!

Here is my web applicaiton:

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <p>Document Name</p>
        <input id="documentName" value="blah.pdf" />
        <button id="startDownload" disabled="disabled">Start Download</button>
        <p id="message"></p>
    </div>
    <asp:PlaceHolder runat="server">
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js"></script>
        <script src="Scripts/json2.min.js"></script>
        <script src="<%: ResolveClientUrl("~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.2.1.js") %>"></script>
        <script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {
                var download = $.connection.fileCreatedHub;

                $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
                    $("#startDownload").click(function () {
                        var fileName = $("#documentName").val();
                        if (fileName.length === 0) {
                            alert('Must have document name.');
                        } else {
                            $('#startDownload').attr('disabled', true);
                            download.server.startDownload(fileName)
                                .fail(function (result) {
                                    alert(result);
                                });
                        }

                    });

                    $('#startDownload').removeAttr('disabled');
                }).fail(function () {
                    alert('Failed to connect!');
                });

                download.client.sendMessage = function (response) {
                    $('#startDownload').removeAttr('disabled');
                    $('#message').text(response);
                };
            });

        </script>
    </asp:PlaceHolder>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the a Global.asax.cs Application_Start

```
protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

Here is RouteConfig class

```
public static class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs();
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls();
    }
}
```

Here is my hub

```
[HubName("fileCreatedHub")]
public class FileCreatedHub : Hub
{
    public void StartDownload(string fileName)
    {
        var context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<FileCreatedHub>();
        context.Clients.Client(Context.ConnectionId).sendMessage("Received " + fileName);
    }
}
```

***Edit 1***
IE network log

```
URL Method  Result  Type    Received    Taken   Initiator   Wait‎‎  Start‎‎ Request‎‎   Response‎‎  Cache read‎‎    Gap‎‎
http://10.3.102.234/download2.aspx  GET 200 text/html   2.02 KB 2.41 s  refresh 0   47  2355    16  0   874
/signalr/hubs   GET 404 text/html   160 B   109 ms  <script>    2418    0   109 0   0   765
/Scripts/json2.min.js   GET 200 application/x-javascript    2.96 KB 203 ms  <script>    2418    0   156 47  0   671
/Scripts/jquery.signalR-1.2.1.js    GET 200 application/x-javascript    110.83 KB   0.65 s  <script>    2418    0   156 499 0   219
/Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.js    GET 200 application/x-javascript    232.84 KB   0.74 s  <script>    2418    0   109 640 0   125
```

***Edit 2***
After viewing the IE network traffic, I noticed IE was requesting /signalr/hubs as text/html,

so I changed:

```
<script src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="signalr/hubs"></script>
```

However, it's still requesting it as text/html, even though when I view source it's correct.  I'm wondering if this may be the issue?

Anyway, thanks in advance for anyone's help!

Comment: is asp.net installed/turned on on your 2008 R2 server?

Comment: Yes, it's installed.  Thhe page comes up as you would expect, however I get a javascript error "Error: SignalR: Error loading hubs. Ensure your hubs reference is correct, e.g. <script src='/signalr/hubs'></script>.".  The reason I'm getting this is because a 404 error when calling http://myserver/signalr/hubs.

Comment: Are you adding anything to your RouteTable before your call to MapHubs?

Comment: Nope, I posted exactly what I have. I just can't figure out what's going on.

Comment: Can you check your browser's network tab in dev tools and post the details of the requests you're seeing please?

Comment: I put the IE network information above in my edit, which is pretty much the same thing I get from fiddler.  If you want a screenshot, let me know.

Comment: Just now looking the IE network information, I notice /signalr/hubs is getting requested as text/html and not application/javascript.  Maybe this could be the problem?

Comment: Any thoughts on what could be causing it?